# developing web interface in illustrator; font aliasing

Tags: text, font-face

illustrator shows the font/text aliased compared to the way the browser interprets it
the difference is noticeable here

[image]

(in chrome:)
the bottom is illustrator, and as you can see, it's a bit bolder and smoother.. is there a setting I can change in illustrator so I can see how it will look when I actually output it to the website ?

if I disable Aliasing artwork, it looks completely off.
this is more evident when the text is bigger, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Illustrator has it's own text anti-aliasing modes that differ from what your browser shows you. However, the differences between your examples are minor compared to how different browsers and operating systems render the same fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Preview the image in save for web and devices. (file -> save for web & devices)  I'm assuming you're exporting the image traditionally through file -> export, but save for web & devices shows you how the image will look on the web.  The reason it looks different is because illustrator is a vector-based design program, unlike photoshop which is bitmap, or pixel based.  This means that text in illustrator has infinite resolution until you export it as an image.  If you want a cleaner look for text, go to save for web & devices and select "type optimized" from the menu next to the "apply" button on the right side of the screen.  Then hit "apply" and then "save".

Comment: sorry, that is not relevant